# Java program calculating mean with exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Write a program that calculates the average of N integers. The program should prompt the user to enter the value for N and then afterward must enter all Nnumbers. If the user enters a non-positive value for N then an exception should be thrown (and caught) with the message "N must be positive." If there is any exception as the user is entering the N numbers then an error message should be displayed and the user prompted to enter the number again. If the user does not enter an integer, the program must request the use to re-enter the value.

Am i throwing the exception correctly??

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int sum = 0, mean;
        System.out.println("Please enter number of integers");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = sc1.nextInt();

        if ( counter <= 0 ) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("N must be positive");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter "+counter+" numbers");
        }

        for (int i =0; i< counter; i++) {
            int inputnum = sc1.nextInt();
            if ( inputsum <= 0){
                throw new InputMismatchException("Please enter again");
                continue;
            }
            sum = sum+inputnum;
            System.out.println();
        }


        mean = sum/counter;

        System.out.println(mean);

    }
}
```

Comment: No, you're not doing it correctly. From your question: "*should be thrown (**and caught**)*" - You're not catching the exception. The `continue` you have after `throw` is actually unreachable code.

Comment: Replace `throw new InputMismatchException("Please enter again");` with `System.err.println("Please enter again");`, and everthing will work as expected. Read a tutorial about exceptions.

Comment: Although you want to ask your user to enter the input again, your for loop is still ticking. Also, even though the number is non positive, you are still adding it to your sum whereas you are supposed to discard it. These are a couple of more problems apart from the exception handling which has been mentioned by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrown exceptions are **caught** by the innermost enclosing `try/catch` statement which matches the exception class.
In this case the `try/catch` statement is outside your main method. 
In other words, when an exception is thrown, it gets caught **outside** the main function, and your program will finish.

Exceptions are particularly useful when we have an error inside a called function and we need to report it to the caller bypassing the return value, which then doesn’t need to reserve a value for the errors.

In this line.

```
throw new InputMismatchException("Please enter again");
continue;
```

`continue` will never get reached by the control since `throw` (like a `return`) makes the control leave the method.

If you replace that `throw` with a simple `System.out.println` describing the problem your program will work as you expect though.

**Edit:** since you need a concrete example, consider your `for` statement. You use `Scanner#nextInt()` to get the next number.
It may throw an `IllegalStateException` if the `Scanner` finished its input source? Then:

```
try {
     for (int i =0; i< counter; i++) {
               /* … */
     }
} catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
     System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

If any `IllegalStateException` occurs, this makes the control jump in the `catch` clause, making it go out of the `for` statement with no effort.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It makes total sense now but in the question itself there are some throws provided.      Throws: 
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed. So I am just wondering if I could make my program better or more valid to the question by using those as appropriately as i can?

Comment: Using `throw` itself in your code makes no sense if your program doesn’t provide an “interface” to something but it’s just a simple program that takes its inputs and gives its output. By the way if you really want to use them you can use try/catch statements. I will make you an example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this better or is there something wrong as well?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.IllegalStateException;

public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum =0, mean;
        System.out.println("Please enter no.");
        Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = sc1.nextInt();
        if ( counter <=0){
            throw new InputMismatchException("not valid no.");
        }
        else {
            try {
                for (int i = 0;i<counter;i++){
                    int inputsum= sc1.nextInt();
                    sum = inputsum+sum;
                    System.out.println();
                }
                mean = sum/counter;
                System.out.println(mean);
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException | NoSuchElementException | InputMismatchException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage);
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage);
        }
    }
}
```